# Where to learn how to formulate claims

Tags: claims

I'm interested in learning about how to formulate claims. Can people suggest books? Preferably with examples related to questions within the chemical sciences and for the european area.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best books about (U.S.) claims is [Invention Analysis and Claiming: A Patent Lawyer's Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1402411340). It does *not* use chemistry examples. Chemical patent claiming is definitely a specialty within a specialty.

Landis (now Faber) [Faber on Mechanics Patent Claim 6th Ed](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1402411340)  has a chapter on chemical claims. It is over $350 but you might find a copy at a specialized law library.

Someone else may be able to recommend references on European patent law.